# Using glClear() when there are multiple shader programs

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl

Suppose I want to render an OpenGL scene in two viewports. The first viewport renders a colour image, and the second viewport renders a depth image. Each has its own vertex shader and fragment shader, and each has its own shader program. The shaders are similar, the only difference being that for the colour image, the vertex colour is defined in the vertex shader based on the vertex normal, whereas for the depth image, the vertex colour is defined in the fragment shader based on the vertex depth. To perform the rendering, I `glUseProgram()` the colour shader program, and draw the colour scene, then `glUseProgram()` the depth shader program, and draw the depth scene.

What I am unsure about, is how `glClear()` works when there are two shader programs. Do I need to call it twice per rendering loop -- once before rendering the colour image, and once before rendering the depth image? It seems to work when I just call it once, but this seems strange to me. I would have thought that each shader program writes to the colour and depth buffer once each. Therefore, when rendering the depth image, it would have the buffers left over from rendering the colour image...but this does not seem to be the case. Can somebody explain this to me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> What I am unsure about, is how glClear() works when there are two shader programs.

If you're unsure about how clearing interacts with shaders, then you have some kind of misunderstanding of what's going on.

`glClear` [clears the framebuffer](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Clear). What shader programs were used to create the pixels in that framebuffer is entirely irrelevant. It doesn't matter how many programs were used to generate the pixel data.

It's conceptually no different from this:

```
int foo = <insert large expression here>;
foo = 5;
```

No matter how large and complicated the initialization expression is, writing 5 to the variable will overwrite whatever was there. Just as clearing the framebuffer will *clear the framebuffer*, no matter how it got there.

> Do I need to call it twice per rendering loop -- once before rendering the colour image, and once before rendering the depth image?

Viewports are not real constructs in OpenGL. They're simply a part of the [NDC-to-window-space transformation](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Viewport_Transform). Your vertices, after clipping, are transformed to a location within the window; the viewport simply lets you decide where within the window they go. You don't see parts that would be outside of the viewport because those vertices were clipped by the clipping stage.

Viewports do not create framebuffers, sub-framebuffers, mini-framebuffers, or anything having to do with framebuffers. Viewports are just a transformation trick for primitives.

And framebuffer clearing operations do not involve [primitives](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Primitive). As such, framebuffer clears *do not care* about the current viewport. They will affect the entire framebuffer.

Framebuffer clears *do* respect the [scissor box](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Scissor_Test), if scissor testing is enabled when you issue the clear. But *viewports* are irrelevant to clearing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still a little confused though... So when I render my scene using the colour shader program, it writes data to the frame buffer and the depth buffer, which are then used to render to the screen using the viewport for my colour image. Then, I switch to using the depth shader program, and render to the viewport for my depth image. Wouldn't this then write to that same frame buffer and depth buffer? Still with all the data written to it when rendering with the colour shader program?